# Docker: Why port forwarding is not working with go tour?

Tags: docker

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM golang:latest
EXPOSE 3999
ENTRYPOINT ["go", "tool", "tour"]
```

It starts the [Go Tour](https://tour.golang.org) at http://localhost:3999

I'm running it with docker `run -d -p 127.0.0.1:3999:3999 "hubusername/docker-tour:v1"`

But `$ curl http://localhost:3999` returns an error:
*curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer*

Of course, ip:3999 in browser doesn't work too.

p.s. `docker run -d -p 8081:80 nginx:alpine` works perfect

Comment: It's probably because the go tour is only bound to the container's local IP (127.0.0.1), and not its external IP, which is what `-p` forwards.

Comment: @afontaine May I forward -p to 127.0.0.1?

Comment: There is likely an option allowing `go tour` to bind to a different IP address. If you pass in `0.0.0.0` to that option, it usually binds on all IP addresses. Is there a `-h` or a `--host` option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I've just setted a 0.0.0.0 host to go tour application by adding this line:

> CMD ["-http", "0.0.0.0:3999", "-openbrowser=false"]

Answer (score 0):

I got this working using the default golang container with:

```
docker run --rm -p 3999:3999 golang go tool tour -http 0.0.0.0:3999 -openbrowser=false
```